# Anonymous type-casting in php

Tags: php

Is there a way to type cast one variable(`$first`) to the type of the other variable(`$second`).

**Example:**

```
$first = 2;
$second = "some data";
```

I want to get type of `$second` and make `$first = "2"`. Or if `$second=false`, `$first` is to be converted to `true`.

> **Question:** *Fetch type from One variable and convert second variable as type of the first variable*.

Comment: I wondered if there is a method to do this or not.
It is good now....Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are functions for that:

```
settype($first, gettype($second));
```

Comment: Thanks. @AbraCadaver.

Answer (score 0):

I dont believe php

In most cases the cast is not needed, since a value will be automatically converted. It may not be obvious exactly what will happen when casting between certain types. For more information, see these sections:

php manual  http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php